# MATLAB won't return my outputs

Tags: matlab

I have written a function in MATLAB but it will not return my outputs.  It returns the first output as ans=a # but that's it. I thought `function[argout1,argout2,...argoutn=funcname(in1,in2,...inn)` returns all outputs in the format `argout1= a #`, `argout2= a #`  and so on.

I realize I could use `disp()` or some other built in function but what is the point in all that when you have a function file. The function is accessing the inputs from an excel spreadsheet but I didn't think that should make a difference. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The code is as follows.

```
function[y_int1, y_int2, Youngs_Modulus, Poissons_Ratio, Youngs_Modulus_Percent_diff, Poissons_Ratio_Percent_diff, RMS1, RMS2]= Lab3_EC(elong1,elong2,elat1,elat2,thick,width,load,N)



%average longitudinal strain
avgLongs=((elong1)+(elong2))/2;



%average lateral strain
avgLats=((elat1)+(elat2))/2;


%Find's the area of the sample

A=thick*width;


%Finds the applied stress
stress=load./A;


%declares a variable x1 for Long Strain
x1=avgLongs;


%declares a variable y1 for Applied Stress
y1=stress;

%Declares variables to compute slope1

x1bar=mean(x1);
y1bar=mean(y1);
sxy1=sum(x1.*y1);
sx1=sum(x1);
sy1=sum(y1);
sx1s=sum(x1.*x1);
sx11s=(sum(x1))^2;
slope1=(N*sxy1-sx1*sy1)/(N*sx1s-sx11s);
y_int1=y1bar-slope1*x1bar;

%x points
xp=linspace(min(x1),max(x1));

% y points
yp1=slope1*xp+y_int1;

%Declares variables to compute slope 2

%Since our second calculation of linear regression uses Average
%Longitudinal Stress we can re-use the variable x1 

y2=abs(avgLats);
y2bar=mean(y2);
sxy2=sum(x1.*y2);
sy2=sum(y2);
slope2=(N*sxy2-sx1*sy2)/(N*sx1s-sx11s);
y_int2=y2bar-slope2*x1bar;


%y points
yp2=slope2*xp+y_int2;


%preallocate space for error1 vector
Error1=zeros(N,1);

%compute error1
for i=1:N;
   Error1(i)= (stress(i)-y_int1-slope1*avgLongs(i))^2;
end
Error1=sum(Error1(5));   

%preallocate space for error2 vector

Error2=zeros(N,1);
for i=1:N;
    Error2(i)=(abs(avgLats(i))-y_int2-slope2*avgLongs(i))^2;
end
Error2=sum(Error2(5));

RMS1=sqrt(Error1/N);

RMS2=sqrt(Error2/N);


Lab_2_E=(stress(5)-stress(1))/(avgLongs(5)-avgLongs(1));
Lab_2_v=(abs(avgLats(5)-avgLats(1))/(avgLongs(5)-avgLongs(1)));
Youngs_Modulus=slope1;
Poissons_Ratio=slope2;
Youngs_Modulus_Percent_diff=((abs(Youngs_Modulus-Lab_2_E))/Lab_2_E)*100;
Poissons_Ratio_Percent_diff=((abs(Poissons_Ratio-Lab_2_v))/Lab_2_v)*100;



%Plot stress strain diagram and poisson's ratio
figure(1), plot(avgLongs,stress,'k',x1,y1,'o',xp,yp1,':g'),hold on,...
    xlabel('Long Strain(in/in)'),ylabel('Stress(psi)'),...
    title('Stress vs. Long Strain'), legend('Exp','data points','Calc',...
    'Location','SouthEast')
figure(2),plot(avgLongs,abs(avgLats),x1,y2,'+',xp,yp2,'-- m'),hold on,...
    xlabel('Long Strain(in/in)'),ylabel('Lat Strain(in/in)'),...
    title('Poisson''s Ratio'),legend('Exp','data points','Calc',...
    'Location','SouthEast')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume you have a function `fun`:

```
[o1, o2, o3, o4, o5] = fun(i1, i2, i3, i4);
```

If you execute

```
fun(in1, in2, in3)
```

there is only one output argument: `ans` the default output argument. This'll get the value of the first output argument defined in your function header (namely `o1`).

If you want more outputs, you have to specify them:

```
[out1, out2, out3] = fun(in1, in2, in3);
```

Now `out1`, `out2` and `out3` will respectively contain the values assigned in the function to `o1`, `o2` and `o3`.

You should definitely read through [function documentation](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/function.html).

Comment: Thanks Gunther.  I have programmed a bit before and actually written functions, it has just been spread out.